# Console, how to hide the "New Tab" button

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud

Is it possible to remove/hide the "New Tab" button within the Salesforce Console as below:

[image]

Comment: That'd be pretty self-defeating, don't you think? Why not just switch to Lightning?

Comment: Requirement came way... I couldn't figure it out so thought to ask. I've already raised the Lightning but as we are only rolling out salesforce to our org now we thought it easier to use the console short term (no aura skills in house and the product owners had issues with not being able to customise the left hand menu etc). Thanks

Comment: @sfdcfox Did they release a Lightning ready console? I haven't read every page of the SU16 release notes, but I wasn't aware of a Lightning Ready Console having been released.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to remove or disable the New Tab button in the console through normal setup options. Being able to have multiple tabs is one of the key parts of the console's functionality and so can't be turned off.

That would leave you the option of a custom implementation, probably using javascript to modify that particular DOM element. I'm not sure where you will be able to do that however due to cross-domain security policies at the browser level. Custom console components won't work because VF pages are served from a separate domain and you wouldn't be able to access the console's document to modify it. Same with embedding a VF into a page layout. A VF home page component suffers from the same security rules.

As far as I know, there's no way to run javascript in the console from the top level domain, which means this may be impossible entirely without the use of third party browser tools like Greasemonkey or a custom extension. It would be a fairly trivial matter to write the code necessary, but then you would need your agents to install the extension or tool being used.

The closest I could come is by creating a listview button, but this needs to be added to all of your listviews and manually clicked at least one time after the console opens. After it's clicked once then it can automatically hide the icon for new tabs that are opened.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/37.0/integration.js")};

var hideNewTabButton = function() { 
    var buttons = parent.document.getElementsByClassName('add-tab-btn');
    for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) { 
        buttons[i].style.visibility="hidden";
    }
}

//Every time a new tab is opened it will hide the button in the subtab panel as well
sforce.console.addEventListener(sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.OPEN_TAB, hideNewTabButton);

//Run once on load for primary tab panel
hideNewTabButton();
```

Overall this seems like an impossible task to do entirely within Salesforce due to the security implementations that are in place. If you actually find a way to do it I might even consider it a security flaw because then in theory a malicious package could do the same, but choose to do something much worse than hide an icon. If you can help the requester redefine the requirement (is it really just about the icon, or did someone hand you a solution without defining a problem) you may be able to find an implementation that suits their needs.